# Is Faye compatible with all browsers?

Tags: real-time, websocket, publish-subscribe, faye

I'm considering [Faye](http://faye.jcoglan.com/) for some real-time pub/sub to browser clients. I can't find any information about which browsers do and don't work with Faye.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

(Disclaimer: I'm the author of Faye.)

Faye runs in all the major browsers as well as WebKit-based mobile browsers on iPhone, iPad and Android devices. It should run in any browser capable of one of the following:

- WebSockets (including the Firefox 6 and Chrome 14 implementations as of 0.6.4)
- XMLHttpRequest
- CORS
- JSON-P